# PsiReferenceContributor not catching element

Tags: intellij-plugin

I have a simple test class:

```
public class Test {    
    public void foo() {
        Object a = getClass();
    }
}
```

Playing with the DefinitionsReferenceContributor I expect it to get the reference, but nothing happens. Breakpoint inside getReferencesByElement is not reached.

```
public class DefinitionsReferenceContributor extends PsiReferenceContributor {


    @Override
    public void registerReferenceProviders(PsiReferenceRegistrar registrar) {

        PsiElementPattern.Capture<PsiMethodCallExpression> psiJavaTokenCapture = psiElement(PsiMethodCallExpression.class);

        registrar.registerReferenceProvider(psiJavaTokenCapture, new PsiReferenceProvider() {
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public PsiReference[] getReferencesByElement(@NotNull PsiElement element, @NotNull ProcessingContext context) {
                
                return new PsiReference[0];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Changes to plugin.xml:

```
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
  <depends>com.intellij.java</depends>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <psi.referenceContributor implementation="DefinitionsReferenceContributor"/>
  </extensions>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
    PsiElementPattern.Capture<PsiLiteralExpression> psiLiteralExpressionCapture = PlatformPatterns.psiElement(PsiLiteralExpression.class);
    registrar.registerReferenceProvider(psiLiteralExpressionCapture, psiReferenceProvider, PsiReferenceRegistrar.HIGHER_PRIORITY);
```

This fires the

> public PsiReference[] getReferencesByElement(PsiElement psiElement,
> ProcessingContext processingContext)

Method where i can process the element according to my needs.